# How to write a protected MATLAB script/program?

Tags: matlab, obfuscation, matlab-deployment

I need to write a MATLAB script/program to a client; and I need to hide the code. The client will only able run the program but will not be able to read the code. May I know how I can do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`pcode` function creates protected `.p` files.

Answer (score 3):

compile it: http://www.mathworks.nl/products/compiler/

> Encrypts MATLAB code so that it cannot be viewed or modified

Answer (score 1):

Try [pcode](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/pcode.html).

nothing to add, just getting over the minimum answer size

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [`pcode`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/pcode.html). The alternative is to compile the code to binary, as others have suggested. See [Protecting Your Source Code](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f7-38053.html#bsc58yj-1).